# Prestashop, devloping module, and my DB request returns false

Tags: module, prestashop

I'm trying to get customer data in prestashop, but my query returns false. My code:

```
        $sql = Db::getInstance()->getValue('SELECT id FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'customer WHERE email = '.Tools::getValue('email'));

  echo '<script>';
  echo 'console.log("id of element: '. json_encode( $sql ) .'")';
  echo '</script>';
```

I'm new to module developing so any advice will be helpfull.

Comment: Just add `echo 'SELECT id FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'customer WHERE email = '.Tools::getValue('email');` and see what is your SQL statement. Ant you can run this SQL directly in i. e. phpMyAdmin to check if it is returning anything.

Comment: I've tried to, but nothing happened. that's why i echoed console log which stated "false"

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong column name. Should by id_customer

Comment: I've managed to do it, by looking at customer.php:

$fgmcustomer = Db::getInstance()->getRow('
  SELECT *
  FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'customer`
  WHERE `email` = \''.pSQL($tempemail).'\'
  '.Shop::addSqlRestriction(Shop::SHARE_CUSTOMER).'
  '.(isset($passwd) ? 'AND `passwd` = \''.pSQL(Tools::encrypt($passwd)).'\'' : '').'
  AND `deleted` = 0
  '.($ignore_guest ? ' AND `is_guest` = 0' : ''));

$strippedid = $fgmcustomer['id_customer'];